# I can't get the value of my selected option

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a `select` field with some options.
The thing is that when I try to get the `value` of the selected option, I get the default value of the list.

Here's my code:

```
   <div id='aux_motivo'>
      <select name='id_aux_motivo' id='id_aux_motivo' class="combo4" >
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="1"  >Opt 1</option>
                            <option value="2"  >Opt 2</option>
                            <option value="3"  >Opt 3</option>
                            <option value="4"  >Opt 4</option>
                            <option value="5"  >Opt 5</option>
      </select>(*)
   </div>
```

This is the code I use for getting the `value`:

```
var id_aux_motivo=$('#id_aux_motivo').val();
```

For some reason, instead of getting the value from the option I choose, I keep getting "", as if I chose "Select".

PS:Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: your code looks ok: https://jsfiddle.net/xqmesL67/ - which version of jQuery are you using? Where/when do you call the code to get the value of the select?

Comment: You haven't wrapped the `var` in a function like Lorenzo has in his fiddle. It's getting assigned on page load which is why its going to `""` as its loading the default value.

Comment: In fact, I put the `select` in a `dialog`, and the `var` gets assigned when I click Continue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I used `var id_aux_motivo= $(this).find(":selected").val() ;`
to assign the value to the variable.

Other options didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Bind an event handler to the "change" event, or trigger that event on the element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_aux_motivo').on("change", function () {
        var id_aux_motivo = $('#id_aux_motivo').val();
        console.log(id_aux_motivo);
    });
});

</script>;
```

Try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ro5oarm/) example.

Comment: I tried using an `alert` on change, but I keep getting the default value.

Comment: @EstebanSandoval this must work. And please, fix your **quote** and **double quote** for the tag attributes.

Comment: Not sure which tag you are taking about, anyway - if you are happy with the answer, please accept it by selecting the check mark adjacent to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First check your HTML ID `id_aux_motivo`, it should be unique.
If it is, then the below listed solutions will work:

```
var id_aux_motivo= $("#id_aux_motivo").find(":selected").val() ;
alert(id_aux_motivo);
```

or

```
alert($("#id_aux_motivo").val());
```